# Regular Expression, end phrase extraction

Tags: regex

I want to extract the project name, which is “TGP for ABC” from the sentence:
“Project ID for project TGP for ABC”.

Could someone suggest the RegEx pattern please? The project name could be 2-4 words.

Comment: /.*project\s(.+) worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will work:

```
/.*project\s(.+)/g
```